# Communication between FireFox bootstrap script and page script

Tags: firefox-addon

I have FireFox bootstrap addon to communicate with native application through js-ctypes. This addon should be used as proxy providing connection between web-page and my native application. How can I send request from page script to bootstrap script and get response with minimal efforts?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to CustomEvent and dispatch CustomEvent from page.

This addon here listens to CustomEvent

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9288991

Comment: Good solution, but how to get response? If I will dispatch event from bootstrap script when request completed back to page script, it will be difficult to process the result of request because of different running context.